# Returning list of ids from repository

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am not able to return list of ids on my questions. I have the exact same query that returns question objects instead and it works. Any reason why this shouldn't be working. All it gives me is a list which is empty.  Zero elements.

```
@NamedQuery(name = Question.FIND_ALL_IDS_FOR_STATE_APPROVED, query = "SELECT q.id FROM Question q WHERE q.state = :state")
```

and:

```
@Override
public List<Integer> findAllIdsForApprovedQuestions() {

    final TypedQuery<Integer> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(Question.FIND_ALL_IDS_FOR_STATE_APPROVED, Integer.class);
    query.setParameter("state", QuestionState.APPROVED);
    final List<Integer> ids = query.getResultList();

    return ids;
}
```

What is returned when you query for attributes on an entity, and how should you deal with that?

Comment: You mean `SELECT q FROM Question q WHERE q.state = :state` returns you list of questions with exact same set of steps(except changing Integer to Question)?

Comment: Can you try without `resultClass` parameter?